# What do the replicants' eyes imply about the process of their creation?

Tags: blade-runner-series, blade-runner-2049

It was explicit in Blade Runner that the eyes are made separately -- the old technician/scientist that Roy and the other Replicant accost makes eyes.

Okay: So they are made separately and put in later? But the Replicant we see "born" in front of Nicander Wallace I think already had eyes -- that I guess doesn't mean they are not added to the body before birth.

Do we know anything about the process? Are Replicants grown or is it pretty clear they are assembled, perhaps in addition to eyes, other parts are made separately and added? If so, the sack in which the Replicant was before "birth", very much like a placenta is not a place where Replicants are grown but merely where they are kept after assembly? Is there some process they undergo after assembly that requires that they be in this placenta-like container?

Is this discussed in any of the books?

Comment: The original book (singular), *Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?* did not, to my recollection, include much detail  of how the androids were made -- but then even the first Bladerunner movie departed pretty vigorously from the book.

Comment: @ZeissIkon: No Sheep did not go into it but maybe some of the non-Dick books might have. I am not sure that the writers have a clear view of what the Replicants are. In Blade Runner, it almost seems like they were showing that they had electrical components but also they mention clearly their biological nature.

Comment: Chew says he 'just does eyes', but it's not made clear exactly *what* he does with them. Perhaps he constructs them separately during the design process, but then the bioengineering schematic he creates is incorporated into the overall Replicant blueprint? I don't think it necessarily implies that every Replicant's eyes are made separately.

Comment: Except he seems to be growing them in volume -- I feel it is implied that these are eyes that end up in Replicants and indeed he says, "I made your eyes." This is different than "I designed your eyes."

Comment: We are talking about different generations of replicants with different proccess most likely.

Comment: @Ram Nonetheless, the latest generation still has serial numbers on their eyes which implies that the eyes are still made separately -- I guess the eyes could be programmed to grow with serial numbers but I think this deliberately reminds of us the vat-grown eyes.